# Correct Sealant / Caulk for fixing LED Down Light

Tags: led, sealing, sealant

I have recently had LED down lights installed in my ceiling. 
In strong winds I am finding some granulated loft insulation is blown through around the light fixings. 
I would like to seal around them - what should i use to do this?

Silicone would be hard to paint. Would decorators Caulk "stick"?  any advice appreciated i am in UK.

Comment: As Jack pointed out, caulk isn't a good fix here. Please provide more detail about the type of fixture and the ceiling finish. There's almost certainly a better solution to be had than gooing up your lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ‘paintable’ silicone caulks, if the gaps are not very large that may be a good choice. Look for that keyword when selecting. You could also use drywall paste (plaster? Not sure of the term in UK) If you need flexibility, like if the fixture may move relative to the ceiling, silicone is a good choice, but if not and it’s only small gaps (<=10mm) them maybe a latex caulk, paintable again. For larger gaps you’ll want to fill them first. You could use something like butyl cord or strips, but push them up above the surface because they won’t hold paint, then cover with calk or plaster.

Comment: There is caulk called "painters caulk" which should save you the trouble of trying to determine if the caulk is paintable.

Comment: Thank you i found a flexible acrylic paintable Caulk  "Geocel Painters Mate Flexible Acrylic Filler White"

Answer (score 2):

I would shy away from caulk just because you might have to remove the ring/trim in the future and caulk would make that difficult. Have you thought about using some weather stripping? It comes in various thicknesses and colors and is self adhesiving. It's easy to use and less messy than caulk.

Comment: gaps are only 2-3mm thick where the core drill made a ragged hole so i don't thik weather stripping would help, thanks though